# How to let ALL return false when subquery no records?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

My SQL like this:

```sql
select * from tb where col=ALL(subquery)
```

when `subquery` no records, `col=ALL(subquery)` will return `true`, how to let it return `false`?

Answer (score 3):

The only way I'm aware of is to repeat the subquery inside an `Exists` operator:

```
SELECT ColumnsList
FROM TableName
WHERE Col = ALL(subquery)
AND EXISTS(subquery)
```

If the subquery is long and/or complicated, you can encapsulate it inside a common table expression to shorten your code:

```
WITH cte(col) AS
(
  -- subquery here
)
SELECT ColumnsList
FROM TableName
WHERE Col = ALL(SELECT col FROM cte)
AND EXISTS(SELECT col FROM cte)
```

Hopefully, the optimizer is smart enough to do the `exists` before the `all`.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see why you are using `ALL` with `=`. As per the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/all-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

> If the subquery returns values of 2 and 3, scalar_expression = ALL
>   (subquery) would evaluate as FALSE, because some of the values of the
>   subquery (the value of 3) wouldn't meet the criteria of the
>   expression.

So, in your case makes more sense to use `IN` and if the sub-query returns `no values`, nothing will be returned.

Otherwise, use the `EXISTS` clause as Zohar said.

Comment: One possible use case is that when you want to make sure the subquery returns only one distinct value, regardless of how many records it returns. `IN` is a good analogy to `= ANY` or `= SUM`, not to `= ALL`